# check server existing / Online using xpages

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I not sure how to check whether the server, i plan to accessing is online or existed using xpages javascript.

Below i always check my database is exist or not. but not server. Is there a way to check server is online/existed?

```
var svr:string = getComponent("MailSvr").getValueAsString();
var dbpath:string = getComponent("MailLoc").getValueAsString();

var db:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase(svr, dbpath, false);
if (db == null) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Don’t use getComponent().getValue(). Use databinding and access the data

Comment: yes. already use data binding method

Comment: We should have Kopi soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for the names.nsf on the server. The names.nsf should always be available and accessible, if the server is accessible.